# How to stop Google suggesting the search engine to search in in the address bar?

Tags: google-chrome

When searching for something like "google search console" or "google translate" or "google maps" or anything with google in front, Chrome will replace the term google with a placeholder representing the site I will search in, in this case, Google UK, my default search engine.

What this means is, instead of searching google for "google translate" its searching Google UK for just "translate". The results I obtain are many other translate websites and not "google translate"

Typing in this:

[image]

Replaces with this:

[image]

How can I disable this? I want to actually search the phrase "google something" and not the word "something" in Google.

Comment: Have you tried quoting the search string?

Comment: Probably you've a [custom search engine](https://zapier.com/blog/add-search-engine-to-chrome/) defined which hijacks your "Google" keyword

Comment: Yes I have defined a custom search engine, but I dont want it to replace the search term Google with it

Comment: Still extremely annoying... search for ""google billing" returns results only for billing with no mention of links to "google billing". At least when I search for "google maps", "google search". "google webmaster" etc they do often show their own pages top, so its not so bad. But sometimes like with billing they dont.